# google-cloud-storage library cannot be installed in Python 3.7

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, speech-to-text

For a project I need to import google-cloud-storage library in python to use speech to text service. While trying to install it via pip, I keep getting the below error:

" Looking in indexes: https://www.artifactrepository.clientdomain.net/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-dev/simple Collecting google-cloud-storage   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-cloud-storage (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for google-cloud-storage"

note that , I have been working inside client domain and the python version I am working with is 3.7.3

I have tried different workarounds available in web and still can't resolve the error. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Are you authenticated with pip to the artifacts repo? also does this repo contains the newest version of the client lib?

Comment: have you tried to pip install the latest version of the library directly `pip install google-cloud-storage==2.1.0`?

Comment: The below thread may help you.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2454

Comment: @JackWotherspoon tried this , but did not work

Comment: @AtefH. How to do that ? And is it necessary ? Because I have seen it working in other systems without any issues. And for sure they did not do any authentication.

Comment: @Niladri The error says it is looking for the lib in here `https://www.artifactrepository.clientdomain.net/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-dev/simple`. This does not seem a public repo so you need to authenticate to it. See [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/authentication/). Otherwise, check your pip settings to not download from this repo and instead use the public pip repo.

Comment: @Niladri Have you tried calling the Python interpreter to run the pip executable module instead? `python3 -m pip install google-cloud-storage==2.1.0`.